# How to create an event using for loop and document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to use a loop and document.getElementtById together to create a mouseover event on  several spans with changing ids. Should I use document.getElementByTagName and no loop instead (just using 'span' tag)?

Here is the html:

```
<span id="test1">really</span>
<span id="test2">really</span>
<span id="test3">really</span>
<span id="test4">bad</span>
```

Here is my javaScript:

```
  var myspan = document.getElementById("test" + i);
  for (var i = 0; i < myspan.length; i++) {

  test.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   

    event.target.style.color = "purple";

    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.style.color = "";
    }, 5000);
  }, false);

  }
```

Comment: `test` doesn't exist, and `myspan` isn't an array and doesn't in fact make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var myspan = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (var i = 0; i < myspan.length; i++) {    
      myspan[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {    
      this.style.color = "green";   

       setTimeout(function() {
          this.style.color = "";
       }.bind(this), 1000);    
  }, false);

}
```

In the snippet above, I changed your code. Personally I prefer using css for it, or the following code

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("span"), function(elem) {
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
        elem.style.color = "green";
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.style.color = "";
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I've been at it since last night and couldn't make it work. I can't believe it only took you a few minutes to do it.